# What is the difference between "gone to become" and "gone on to become"?

Tags: meaning

The phrase is:

```
He's gone to become a legend.
```

My understanding of this phrase is: he doesn't exist any more, he is a legend now.

My friend states that the phrase is incorrect. Correct version should be:

```
He's gone on to become a legend.
```

Which version is correct? If both are, is there a difference in meaning?

UPDATE:
Some clarification of context of this phrase. It was not his purpose to become famous. He existed in the past but does not any more. But instead of being forgotten he became famous.

Comment: Both are understandable. The first is simply missing something after *gone*. What's missing is what determines its actual meaning. Let's pretend it's a conversation about Hollywood. In context, the sentence now becomes *he's gone* ***to Hollywood*** *to become a legend.* So, here, "gone to" means he's gone to a place, and, in that place hopes to become a legend—it has a "present" feel, he's working on it. In the second sentence, none of that is assumed. Rather, he's "progressed"—he's "moved on" or "gone on"—and is now a legend. It's more likely that it's already happened in the past.

Comment: "Gone on" is an idiom, so it seems to fit the flow better.

Comment: 'He's gone to [London] to V ...' uses the 'for the purpose of / with the intention of' _to_. 'He's gone to college to train as a plumber.'

Answer (score 1):

First, a definition of **legend** from [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/legend)

> 1. a popular story handed down from earlier times whose truth has not been ascertained
> 2. a group of such stories: the Arthurian legend.
> 3. a modern story that has taken on the characteristics of a traditional legendary tale
> 4. a person whose fame or notoriety makes him or her a source of exaggerated or romanticized tales or exploits

So, if we assume the first definition of "legend", you're correct - the first sentence would mean that the person is now gone and only his story remains. However people don't (usually) just cease to exist and become legendary (in the "story" sense, definitions 1-3). The sentence also uses [present perfect](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_perfect.htm#perfect) tense, the implication is that the subject at least has the potential to keep going.

The Farlax dictionary of idioms (via [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gone+on)) gives a definition for **"go on"** and it is extensive, but for this usage, I think this is the common interpretation:

> 5. verb To proceed or persist. Well, the party must go on, whether we have caterers or not! Can you believe that wisecracking kid went on to become a doctor?

Or, with a change of tense for the example:

> Can you believe that wisecracking kid **has gone on** to become a doctor?

So, in your friend's example, he has proceeded to become a legend. That is, his fame has grown so much, he is now the source of many stories (definition 4). He is still physically around, though and has not vanished. This is, by far, the more likely meaning.

Comment: I would interpret the first sentence as meaning he has gone somewhere else to achieve his goals; e.g. "He has gone [to Hollywood] to become a [movie] legend." (it works better with actor than legend!)